# printer problem ubuntu 20.04 localhost not available, remove ippusbxd?

Tags: 20.04, printing, localhost

Canon MF232w works with my mac, want to use it alone via usb with my HP desktop.  Installed canon MF230 series linux driver 3 times in 20.04 LTS on my HP desktop that has printed with my  just defunct OfficeJet Pro. Printer settings box entry for canon MF230 series is unstable after setup--shows one printer, but alternate accessions of dialog box show address as Localhost or ._ipp._tcp.local/  Localhost option gives printer not connected or not responding in troubleshooting.  The other option works. Some apps show one MF232w printer (LibreOfficeWriter) and I know not which address it is.  Other apps (Firefox) show two, but I don't know which one will work. I checked my cupsd.conf, but don't know what to remove or add--others suggest add Localhost:631 or Port 631 which don't seem to help.  Remove something from cupsd.conf or remove ippusbxd? What other functionality could I lose by removing ippusbxd?

Answer (score 0):

`ippusbxd` essentially auto-configures a USB connected printer when it is plugged in. You will lose that functionality if it is removed from the system. That's all.

OTOH, `ippusbxd` is decidedly sub-optimal. Even its author would support your removing it from your system. It has been replaced by `ipp-usb` in later editions of Ubuntu. There is a 20.04 Debian package [here](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_20.04/amd64/) should you wish to have a better experience of auto-setup on USB.

Otherwise, stick with the vendor drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.  I have performed some of the diagnostics at: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems#AppArmor_Protection_of_the_printing_system

(a very helpful page), installing AppArmor as recommended.  The tail command in the USB section of the wiki was most informative.

I removed ippusbxd, and Voila!  USP Direct Printing! Printer shows up in printer.conf, .brf, and so on.  Now I'll just hope the environment does not become unstable, again, after a major linux base update, such as on Jan 29, the day I lost printer capability.

Problem Solved, for now.